# VBA form- where are my carriage returns?

Tags: vba, excel, visio

I have a textbox in a vba form.  I need the different lines to be assigned to different rows in a spreadsheet.  For this i need to find the carriage return so that i can use the split function to read the values into an array, then drop them in excel.

I can see no obvious carriage return in the string from the textbox.  I cant see an obvious way to enable/disable the addition of them.  How do i add them?

Comment: have you made it multiline?

Comment: have you checked instr(1,textbox.value,vbcrlf) see if there is one?

Comment: I actually just looked at the imediates window and debug.print (neither of which are showing anything).  I will try the instr shortly